# Using the 'for loop' - if there are duplicate words on user input, only the first duplicate word shows. How can I display all duplicate words?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, split

**I am doing a per-word character-counter from a user input.**

However, it seems that if there are duplicate words (of the similar case) from the input, my codes will only output the first word (the duplicates will not be included).

*I have used the split, len and for loop for this.*

```
sentence = input("Enter a sentence: ")
splitting = sentence.split()

final = {x:len(x) for x in splitting}
print(final)
```

- Sample input: New phone alert! Your new phone will be available next week.
- Expected output: {'New': 3, 'phone': 5, 'alert!': 6, 'Your': 4, 'new': 3, 'phone': 5, 'will': 4, 'be': 2 ...}
- Actual output: {'New': 3, 'phone': 5, 'alert!': 6, 'Your': 4, 'new': 3, 'will': 4, 'be': 2 ...}

It shows both 'New' and 'new' as their cases don't match. However, 'phone' is displayed only once.

Comment: Dictionary cannot have duplicate keys. You will not get your desired output using dictionary.

Comment: change z to x in  "for z in splitting", otherwise its an error

Comment: As @SandeepKadapa pointed out. You cannot have duplicate keys in a dictionary. Tell us what are you trying to achieve, are you try to get the word count or character count ?

Comment: Sorry, typo on the variable. I changed z to x on the for loop. I am trying a character count. I am new to Python so I am still figuring out what to do.

Comment: Unless you want to implement your own method, this can be done by `collections.Counter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get word, characterCount in that word in a list of list.

```
listOfList = [[x , len(x)] for x in splitting]
print(listOfList)
```

output:

```
 [['New', 3], ['phone', 5], ['alert!', 6], ['Your', 4], ['new', 3], ['phone', 5], ['will', 4], ['be', 2], ['available', 9], ['next', 4], ['week.', 5]]
```